# Display correctly an array of array within js code using blade

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Under my Laravel controller I have to arrays:

```
$labels   = [6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16];

$datasets = [{
              "label": "Chiron",
              "backgroundColor": "#65e4ff",
              "borderColor": "#65e4ff",
              "data": [0.297619047619, 0.925595238095, 1, 
               0.886904761905, 0.902678571429, 0.993650793651, 
               0.925595238095, 0.915277777778, 0.97619047619, 0.920634920635]
             }];
```

When I pass those php arrays to my view using blade `$label` will work fine but not `$datasets`

```
var barChartData = {
    labels: {{json_encode($labels)}},
    datasets: {{json_encode($datasets)}}
};
```

With the following error :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &

The code source of the page shows :

```
datasets:[{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Chiron&quot...
```

However, doing :

```
var barChartData = {
    labels: {{json_encode($labels)}},
    datasets:<?php echo json_encode($datasets); ?>
};
```

works like a charm. How could I correctly use `blade` to achieve the same result?

**EDIT** : just in case it might cause an error, I use compact to send data to my view. Not sure this is the problem however

```
return view('graphs.chartjs', compact('datasets', 'labels'));
```

**EDIT 2** : I do confirm that `$datasets` is actually an array:

```
dd($datasets)

=>

array:4 [▼
    "label" => "Chiron"
    "backgroundColor" => "#65e4ff"
    "borderColor" => "#65e4ff"
    "data" => array:26 [▶]
  ]
```

Comment: `$datasets` doesn't look like an array, that's JSON already. Don't you get an `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ']'`?

Comment: No. Actually it is an array. If I try to do directly `{!! $datasets !!}` it will throw an error `Array to string conversion`

Comment: Regarding your `dd($datasets)`: where does `"label" => "Fanuc"` appear in your `$datasets`?

Comment: My fault, I extended the scope of my data. Just changed it

Comment: Still doesn't make your `$datasets` a valid PHP array. ;)

Answer (score 0):

update your `$dataset` array like

```
$datasets = [
              "label"=> "Chiron",
              "backgroundColor"=> "#65e4ff",
              "borderColor"=> "#65e4ff",
    "data"=> [0.297619047619, 0.925595238095, 1, 
               0.886904761905, 0.902678571429, 0.993650793651, 
             0.925595238095, 0.915277777778, 0.97619047619, 0.920634920635]
             ];
```

after `json_encode` output look like

```
{
  "label": "Chiron",
  "backgroundColor": "#65e4ff",
  "borderColor": "#65e4ff",
  "data": [
    0.297619047619,
    0.925595238095,
    1,
    0.886904761905,
    0.902678571429,
    0.993650793651,
    0.925595238095,
    0.915277777778,
    0.97619047619,
    0.920634920635
  ]
}
```

Comment: With this array, `{{json_encode($datasets)}}` will still return `datasets:[{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Chiron&quot..`

Answer (score 0):

Within your view file, decode the `datasets` string using:

```
html_entity_decode($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
```

**Edit**

Noticed the curly braces, that isn't a php array, it should be:

```
'key' => 'value'
```

Remove the curly braces and change the like this:

```
"label" => "Chiron"
```

Comment: `{{ html_entity_decode( $datasets , ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')}}` will throw `html_entity_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

Comment: I tried this but changing the curly braces doesn't change. Doing a `dd($datasets)` shows it is an array.

Comment: I can assure you that's incorrect php syntax for an array. The braces are being encoded via `htmlentities` which is why the error is happening. Try passing `true` as a 2nd parameter to `json_encode`

Comment: Just did it with no effect. It's a mystery to me too, I don't get were I have it wrong. Will dig deeper in my code